# Windows 2012 R2 Standard Windows Update Error 800072EFE

Tags: windows, update, wsus

Hyper-V vms running  Windows Update error on Windows 2012 R2 Standard, all having error in updating Windows since installation.

Code

### 800072EFE

Have tried the suggestions as I googled.
E.g. DSIM tool, Windows Update troubleshooting tool, April 2014 rollup fixes, disable secure boot in firmware hyper-v settings, disable firewall, disable enhanced internet browser protection mode

Has anyone got a similar problem?

Thank you in advance.

Daryl

Answer (score 0):

If it helps at all, the meaning of the error code is "ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED", "The connection with the server has been terminated", from WinINet.

Chances are either you have a problem with your network somewhere, or it's something silly like your clock being wrong.